# Passenger and Rails are Code Caching despite correctly loading Development Environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working with a very simple rails application, built from the [Rails Getting Started Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).  I'm running it in a Vagrant development VM using Apache2 and Passenger (libapache2_mod_passenger).  I'm having an issue with code caching.

My Rails app appears to be caching controllers and models, but not views.  I can load new controller or model code by running `sudo service apache2 restart` on the vagrant.  I am correctly setting `RailsEnv development` in my virtual host.  I've tried setting `RackEnv development` both instead and additionally.

I've inspected Rails internal configuration and discovered that it is correctly detecting the development environment.  `Rails.env` returns "development". An inspection of `Rails.application.config` shows that everything is as it should be.

From with in the app through the vagrant:

```
Cache Classes:
--- false
...
Local Requests:
--- true
...
Perform Caching:
--- false
...
Cache Store:
--- :null_store
...
```

Except it is clearly caching classes, because I have to restart the web server in order to get it to load new controller code.

The kicker is that when I run `rails server` on my local machine, no caching occurs.  I can make a change to controller code, refresh the page and the change appears as expected.  That suggests that this has something to do with passenger.  But it isn't page caching, since view changes appear immediately.

The versions I'm working with are:

```
ruby 2.3.2p120 (2016-05-21 revision 55092) [x86_64-linux] 
Rails 5.0.0.1 
Phusion Passenger 5.0.30
```

I'm at a complete loss here.  Any thoughts on where I can look?

**Edited 8/29 ~11 am** --Previous debugging attempts in previous question revisions.

Comment: Can you upload your codebase to GitHub and provide us a link? It will be a lot easier to troubleshoot if we can reproduce on our own machines.

Comment: in your `show` method, instead of finding an article by id, just create a new article with title and text to test the link between the controller and view. If this creates the same error, you'll know it's the link and not some other error.

Comment: @kcdragon I think it may have to do with my passenger configuration.  I've discovered that restarting apache2 reset the cache.

Comment: What path are you trying to hit when you attempt to go to `/articles`?  What ID are you providing?  Strong parameters don't apply to path parameters and would not be part of this issue.

Comment: Why are you using passenger/apache for development? Are you deploying this somewhere? If it is just local development, it is pretty standard to use `rails server`

Comment: @kcdragon Because I like to use Vagrant to keep my development isolated and to develop in an environment as close to production as possible.  I work in several different languages and I've found that my local machine can get pretty gummed up if I don't use a vm environment to isolate the different languages and projects.

Comment: Fair. But as an FYI, you can run `rails server` with Vagrant. I do it all the time and map the port 3000 to the host machine.